# quick and dirty way to know which line raised an exception and see the stack trace, from pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

Let's say I have a really basic program that will throw an exception for sure.  I've added a **pdb.set_trace()** to it and I want be able to look around when an error occurs.

```
import pdb
from random import randint

def two_possible_errors(input):

    try:
        assert input % 2, "error!"
        assert not input % 2, "error!"
    except Exception, e:
        pdb.set_trace()
        raise

two_possible_errors(randint(0,9))
```

My problem is when I catch the exception, I am already at the except clause and I don't really know where the error actually happened.  Typically, I will look around a bit, but if I want to see the stack trace, I need to resume execution and wait till the program crashes.  Is there a better way?

OK, let's start out at the exception.  I could put a message on assert, in this particular case, but that's beside the point.

```
> /Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/explore_pdb_exceptions.py(16)two_possible_errors()
-> raise
(Pdb) e
AssertionError('error!',)
```

At this point, I have no idea which of the two lines errored out.

Let's try **where**.  It returns the current location, not where the exception happened.

```
(Pdb) where
  /Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/explore_pdb_exceptions.py(20)<module>()
-> test()
  /Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/explore_pdb_exceptions.py(18)test()
-> two_possible_errors(randint(0,9))
> /Users/jluc/kds2/wk/explore/explore_pdb_exceptions.py(16)two_possible_errors()
-> raise
```

Let's print line 16, just to be sure:

```
(Pdb) l 16
 11             try:
 12                 assert input % 2, "error!"
 13                 assert not input % 2, "error!"
 14             except Exception, e:
 15                 pdb.set_trace()
 16  ->             raise
 17
 18         two_possible_errors(randint(0,9))
 19
 20     test()
```

In order to actually know where I am, I can let pdb **(c)ontinue** and check out the exit stacktrace.  But now I am out of pdb entirely.  Is there a simple way to get that info from the exception itself instead?  Before continue-ing?

```
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "explore_pdb_exceptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    test()
  File "explore_pdb_exceptions.py", line 18, in test
    two_possible_errors(randint(0,9))
  File "explore_pdb_exceptions.py", line 13, in two_possible_errors
    assert not input % 2, "error!"
AssertionError: error!
```

Comment: try `list` ot `ll` command in the `pdb` interactive shell, that should print your the current location

Comment: you mean try **list** or **l** in pdb?  That gets me my *exception catching* location, not where the *exception occurrence* location.  See my output above.  *Let's print line 16, just to be sure*.  Note that my line #s are a bit out of whack with my sample program, but it still points at the same actual code, i.e. the line right after the pdb.set_trace().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

That should print a traceback for the exception that is currently being handled (the one that triggered the `except` control block).

If typing the commands in `pdb`, it will try to interpret the second one as a `pdb` command. Prevent this by adding a `p` in front of the command.

For reference, the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module.

Comment: Sounded really good, thanks, except that gets me **AttributeError: Pdb instance has no attribute 'do_traceback'**.

Comment: `pdb` is trying to interpret the command, if you type it in pdb, you should try with `p traceback.print_exc()`

Comment: gotcha.  It worked.  **assert input % 2, "error!"**  You rock!  Why do I need the p bit in this case?  I can do other stuff on pdb command line, though I've learned that using short variable names like 's' is not a good ideal.

Comment: `p` is shorthand for `print`, which tells pdb to interpret what follows as python (and if it evaluates to not None, print it). Without it, it assumes you want to run the pdb's `traceback` command, which does not exist.

Comment: that makes sense.  but I can run some functions just fine without the p  **(Pdb) int("6")** => *6*.  or, **(Pdb) string.upper("abc")** => **ABC**.  Anyway, I'll just remember to try using 'p' when pdb starts complaining for some reason.  Txs again.

Comment: That. Most things work without the `p`, because it will usually figure out that if it does not understand what you wrote, it must be python code. But sometimes it won't and you have to add the `p`.